# How can I remove the legend from this boxplot in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Please find `My Data` below.

How can I remove the red, encircled legend from my boxplot?

[image]

I wish to keep the same colors and design. I have tried numerous different solutions, but this has unfortunately not solved the problem.

This might be kinda basic, but simply can't figure out how to solve this. I hope you can help - thanks in advance!

My script is:

```
df <- data.frame(x = as.factor(c(p$WHO.Grade)),
                 y = c(p$ki67pro),
                 f = rep(c("Ki67pro"), c(nrow(p))))



ggplot(df) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(x, y, fill = f, colour = f), outlier.alpha = 0, position = position_dodge(width = 0.78)) +
  scale_x_discrete(name = "", label=c("WHO-I\nn=108","WHO-II\nn=34","WHO-III\nn=1")) +
  scale_y_continuous(name="Ki-67 proliferative index", breaks=seq(0,30,5), limits=c(0,30)) +
  stat_boxplot(aes(x, y, colour = f), geom = "errorbar", width = 0.3,position = position_dodge(0.7753)) +
  geom_point(aes(x, y, fill = f, colour = f), size = 3, shape = 21, position = position_jitterdodge()) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#52C1C76D"), name = "",
                    labels = c("\nTotal cohort\nn=159\n ")) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("#51BFC4"), name = "",
                      labels = c("\nTotal cohort\nn=159\n "))
```

And `My Data`

```
p <- structure(list(WHO.Grade = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), ki67pro = c(1L, 12L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 
3L, 20L, 25L, 7L, 4L, 5L, 12L, 3L, 15L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 3L, 12L, 
10L, 4L, 10L, 7L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 7L, 4L, 7L, 10L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 
5L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 20L, 5L, 0L, 4L, 3L, 0L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
20L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 8L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 12L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
4L, 7L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 10L, 5L, 10L, 3L, 10L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 12L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 
2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 4L, 12L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 6L, 
5L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 
3L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 9L, 10L, 
11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 
25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 
38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 
53L, 54L, 55L, 57L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 
68L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 
81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 85L, 87L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 94L, 96L, 
97L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 101L, 102L, 103L, 104L, 105L, 106L, 107L, 
109L, 110L, 111L, 112L, 113L, 114L, 115L, 116L, 117L, 118L, 119L, 
120L, 121L, 123L, 124L, 125L, 126L, 127L, 128L, 130L, 131L, 132L, 
133L, 134L, 135L, 136L, 137L, 138L, 139L, 140L, 141L, 142L, 143L, 
144L, 145L, 146L, 147L, 148L, 149L, 150L, 151L, 152L, 153L, 154L, 
155L, 156L, 157L, 158L, 159L, 160L, 161L, 162L, 163L, 164L, 165L, 
166L, 167L, 168L, 169L, 170L, 171L, 172L, 173L, 174L, 175L))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use *theme()* as follows:

```
... + theme(legend.position = "none")
```

This should eliminate the legend

reference: https://www.datanovia.com/en/blog/ggplot-legend-title-position-and-labels/